# Leer un archivo CSV y crear un objeto con sus datos

Tags: java, poo, csv

Necesito un poco de ayuda.
Tengo un archivo CSV y lo estoy leyendo así:

```
public class LectorDeArchivosCSV {
private List<Alumno> listaAlumnos;

public LectorDeArchivosCSV() {
    listaAlumnos = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<Alumno> getListaAlumnos() {
    return listaAlumnos;
}

public static void leerCsv() {
    CSVReader csvReader = null;

    try {
        /**
         * Reading the CSV File
         * Delimiter is comma
         * Start reading from line 1
         */
        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("listadoDeAlumnos.csv"), ',', '"', 1);
        //employeeDetails stores the values current line
        String[] alumnoDetails = null;
        //List for holding all the rows
        List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        rows = csvReader.readAll();
        //Read individual row from List of rows
        for (String[] row : rows) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));

        }

    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            //closing the reader
            csvReader.close();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Asi se ve cada row del archivo csv

```
[1, Martin, Lopez]
```

El Integer siendo el codigo del Alumno, String nombre y String apellido.
Necesito por cada row crear un objeto de tipo Alumno con esos datos (ya tengo el constructor hecho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se como es tu constructor de alumno pero lo ideal es que sea así públic Alumno (String [] args) o como mínimo sobrecargarlo. De esta manera podrás instanciar directamente objeto de tipo Alumno pasando la row (todo strings) desde tu lector csv.

Saludos.

David

Comment: Hola david! Entiendo tu respuesta pero el codigo de alumno tiene que si o si ser un integer, ya que en otros metodos hago uso de eso. 
                                                                                                      
              public Alumno(Integer codigoAlumno, String nombre, String apellido){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.codigoAlumno = codigoAlumno;
    }   Si le paso directamente un String[]args me quedaria un solo atributo y no quiero eso.

Comment: Hola Bautista. Piensa que a través de String[] args le pasarás los tres atributos [Alumno, Nombre, Apellido]. Una vez en el constructor solo deberás acceder a cada uno de la siguiente manera args[0] para Alumno. args[1] para Nombre y args[2] para Apellido. Por supuesto del primero deberás hacer un casting a integer pero eso no es problema. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias :)